# Cheapest way to run simple NodeJS app in Google Cloud with some interval

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

What would be the cheapest way to launch Docker container with the app on Google Cloud from prebuilt image, let's say once in 10 minutes?

Comment: I think compute engine and use crontab in it to run after every 10 mins

Comment: Compute engine is expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) without the docker container; they can be [scheduled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function).

If you need the container, use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) (one can build them with [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build)).

Every project comes with it's own private container registry; here's an [example](https://github.com/syslogic/cloudbuild-android) of mine, which shows how to build & tag docker container images and how to use them again. Cloud Build publishes to Pub/Sub, which may trigger a Cloud Function eg. to update a build badge.

Comment: Ha! It just came to me that I could actually run my Docker container with Cloud Build only. Without deploying it anywhere else. Can't I?